# How to redirect DNS to different ports

Tags: networking, dns, minecraft

**TL;DR:**

DNS resolution of a domain(s) must map to `IP:port(s)`, instead of just `IP`.

Example,

`sub1.example.com`  `192.0.2.4:4567`
`sub2.example.com`  `192.0.2.4:5678`

I CAN modify DNS records.

---

I own the domain "Arboristal.com". I also own all sub domains privately on arboristal.com. Such as lg.arboristal or ft.arboristal.com.

Under my DNS settings, Arboristal.com is set to go to our web host who is currently hosting our website.

I have three servers running at my house all running under one public IP address. (71.82.237.27)

I also have three subdomains of Arboristal.com pointing towards my IP address.

Each of the three servers run on their own ports (25565, 25566, 25567)

I want for each subdomain to point to each open port on my IP Address.

Unfortunately when you try to connect to one of these servers using one of the subdomains it only connects to the server that you type the port for.

My situation:

Three servers, each running on a different port. (All portforwarded and working as servers)

- Minecraft server one (25565)
- Minecraft server two (25566)
- Minecraft server three (25567)

I have three subdomains running on my DNS provider (webs.com)

- mc.arboristal.com
- tekkit.arboristal.com
- pvp.artboristal.com

When you use Minecraft to connect to one of these it does automatically through port 25565, meaning that no matter what URL you attempt to connect to it always goes to my IP with the port 25565. Connecting you to Minecraft server one. You CAN type in the port manually, but I would rather keep this as good looking and professional as possible.

So, now that you know my situation, is there any possible way I can make mc.arboristal.com, tekkit.arboristal.com, and pvp.arboristal.com all go to my IP address under different ports without having to specify each port in the provided URL to connect to on the users end?

I can add MX, A (Using this one to connect to the server), CNAME, and TXT records to DNS settings

I can also add Name Servers to DNS settings if I need to use a third party as my DNS provider. (Am willing to do if necessary)

I also have full access to my router at 192.168.0.1 if anything needs to be configured there.

I have only just learned how the internet really functions in the last week so I am unsure if anything here is actually possible. I also may not have the right information about how the internet actually works. Please forgive me for any false information that I may assume about the internet.

Comment: that's a long question man.. can you add a TL;DR

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record):

```
_service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port target.
```

> **Service:** the symbolic name of the desired service.
>
> **Proto:** the transport protocol of the desired service; this is usually either TCP or UDP.
>
> **Name:** the domain name for which this record is valid, ending in a dot.
>
> **TTL:** standard DNS time to live field.
>
> **Class:** standard DNS class field (this is always IN).
>
> **Priority:** the priority of the target host, lower value means more preferred.
>
> **Weight:** A relative weight for records with the same priority.
>
> **Port:** the TCP or UDP port on which the service is to be found.
>
> **Target:** the canonical hostname of the machine providing the service, ending in a dot.

Example:

```
_sip._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 5060 sipserver.example.com.
```

So what I think you're looking for is to add something like this to your [DNS hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file):

```
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 40 25565 mc.arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 25566 tekkit.arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 30 25567 pvp.arboristal.com.
```

(Minecraft supports SRV records, as of 1.3.1, with the service name `minecraft`)

On a side note, I highly recommend you go with a hosting company rather than hosting the servers yourself. It's just asking for trouble with your home connection (DDoS and Bandwidth/Connection Speed), but it's up to you.

Comment: I have an alias that's mapping *.mysite.com to mysite.cloudprovider.com. The wildcard is needed to support various sub-domains. Now I'm introducing another site that lives at the same IP address (but not the same server), but is configured to answer to port 8080. I need special.mysite.com to resolve to this new site. Will this solution work for my situation? The zone file shows this, but either it's not working or it hasn't propagated yet: _sip._tcp.special.mysite.com. 60 IN  SRV 1 1 8080 mysite.cloudprovider.com.

Comment: the codes that you given as an example seem to be load balancing related,  but i think that isn't what s/he is asking for,  what i think s/he wanted was something that would make `mc.arboristal.com` point to `arboristal.com:25565`, `tekkit.arboristal.com` point to `arboristal.com:25565` and i think you get the point. that's what i think by what s/he mean by `good looking and professional`, meaning i think s/he wanted to hide the port number. ps: from my point of view, i think it's safe to assume that `carboristal.com` contain an `A` or `AAAA` record and the sub-domain contain `CNAME` record

Comment: **Important note:** SRV record will not work by itself without an A record. First you have to provide something like: `mc IN A 71.82.237.27`, `tekkit IN A 71.82.237.27` and `pvp IN A 71.82.237.27` (or whatever IP you got).

Comment: I was wondering, does this work automatically or does the app need to support SRV records? __Automatically__ meaning that by querying `sub1.example.com` I in fact query `192.0.2.4:4567` under the hood. - Or does the app that does the request need to support this in the sense that it reads the DNS for SRV records, finds `sub1.example.com` and then sends the request to `192.0.2.4:4567` on its own?

Answer (score 13):

(It's been a while since I did this stuff. Please don't blindly assume that *all* the details below are correct. But I hope I'm not *too* embarrassingly wrong. :))

---

As the previous answer stated, the Minecraft client ([as of 1.3.1](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.3.1#Gameplay_2)) supports [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) lookup using the service name `_minecraft` and the protocol name `_tcp`, which means that if your zone file looks like this...

```
arboristal.com.                 86400 IN A   <your IP address>
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 25565 arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 40 25566 arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 40 25567 arboristal.com.
```

...then Minecraft clients who perform SRV record lookup as hinted in the changelog will use ports 25566 and 25567 with preference (40% of the time each) over port 25565 (20% of the time). We can assume that Minecraft clients who do *not* find and respect these SRV records will use port 25565 as usual.

---

However, I would argue that it would actually be more "clean and professional" to do it using a load balancer such as [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/#method). (I pick Nginx just because I've used it before. I'm not claiming it's uniquely suited to this task. It might even be a *bad* choice for some reason.) Then you don't have to mess with your DNS, and you can use the same approach to load-balance *any* service, not just ones like Minecraft which happen to have done the hard client-side work to look up and respect SRV records. To do it the Nginx way, you'd run Nginx on the `arboristal.com` machine with something like the following in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/arboristal.com`:

```
upstream minecraft_servers {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:25566 weight=1;
    server 127.0.0.1:25567 weight=1;
    server 127.0.0.1:25568 weight=1;
}
server {
    listen 25565;
    proxy_pass minecraft_servers;
}
```

Here we are controlling the load-balancing ourselves on the server side (via Nginx), so we no longer need to worry that badly behaved clients might prefer port 25565 to the other two ports. In fact, now *all* clients will talk to `arboristal.com:25565`! But the listener on that port is no longer a Minecraft server; it's Nginx, secretly proxying all the traffic onto three other ports on the same machine.

We load-balance based on a hash of the client's IP address (`ip_hash`), so that if a client disconnects and then reconnects later, there's a good chance that it'll get reconnected to the same Minecraft server it had before. (I don't know how much this matters to Minecraft, or how SRV-enabled clients are programmed to deal with this aspect.)

Notice that we used to run a Minecraft server on port 25565; I've moved it to port 25568 so that we can use port 25565 for the load-balancer.

A possible disadvantage of the Nginx method is that it makes Nginx a bottleneck in your system. If Nginx goes down, then all three servers become unreachable. If some part of your system can't keep up with the volume of traffic on that single port, 25565, all three servers become flaky. And not to mention, Nginx is a big new dependency in your ecosystem. Maybe you don't want to introduce yet another massive piece of software with a complicated config language and a huge attack surface. I can respect that.

A possible *advantage* of the Nginx method is... that it makes Nginx a bottleneck in your system! You can apply global policies via Nginx, such as rejecting packets above a certain size, or responding with a static web page to HTTP connections on port 80. You can also firewall off ports 25566, 25567, and 25568 from the Internet, since now they should be talked to *only* by Nginx over the loopback interface. This reduces your attack surface somewhat.

Nginx also makes it easier to add new Minecraft servers to your backend; now you can just add a `server` line to your config and `service nginx reload`. Using the old port-based approach, you'd have to add a new SRV record with your DNS provider (and it could take up to `86400` seconds for clients to notice the change) and then *also* remember to edit your firewall (e.g. `/etc/iptables.rules`) to permit external traffic over that new port.

Nginx also frees you from having to think about DNS TTLs when making ops changes. Suppose you decide to split up your three Minecraft servers onto three different physical machines with different IP addresses. Using Nginx, you can do that completely via config changes to your `server` lines, and you can keep those new machines inside your firewall (connected only to Nginx over a private interface), and the changes will take effect immediately, by definition. Whereas, using SRV records, you'll have to rewrite your zone file to something like this...

```
arboristal.com.                 86400 IN CNAME mc1.arboristal.com.
mc1.arboristal.com.             86400 IN A   <a new machine's IP address>
mc2.arboristal.com.             86400 IN A   <a new machine's IP address>
mc3.arboristal.com.             86400 IN A   <a new machine's IP address>
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 20 25565 mc1.arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 40 25565 mc2.arboristal.com.
_minecraft._tcp.arboristal.com. 86400 IN SRV 10 40 25565 mc3.arboristal.com.
```

...and you'll have to leave all three new machines poking *outside* your firewall so that they can receive connections from the Internet. *And* you'll have to wait up to `86400` seconds for your clients to notice the change, which could affect the complexity of your rollout plan. *And* if you were running any other services (such as an HTTP server) on `arboristal.com`, now you have to move them to the `mc1.arboristal.com` machine because of how I did that CNAME. I did that only for the benefit of those hypothetical Minecraft clients who don't respect SRV records and will still be trying to connect to `arboristal.com:25565`.

---

So, I think both ways (SRV records and Nginx load-balancing) are reasonable, and your choice will depend on your personal preferences. I caricature the options as:

- SRV records: "I just need it to work. I don't want complexity. And I know and trust my DNS provider."
- Nginx: "I foresee `arboristal.com` taking over the world, or at least moving to a bigger machine someday. I'm not scared of learning a new tool. What's a zone file?"

Comment: I tried to read up on nginx, but from this post I do not see how it would map the subdomains to its specified server. It only seems to do loadbalancing, not mapping?
You don't want to get to a random server if your friend is on the other.

Answer (score 11):

Since I had troubles understanding this post here is a simple explanation for people like me. It is useful if:

- You DO NOT need Load Balacing.
- You DO NOT want to use nginx to do port forwarding.
- You DO want to do PORT FORWARDING according to specific subdomains using SRV record.

Then here is what you need to do:

SRV records:

```
_minecraft._tcp.1.12          IN SRV    1 100 25567 1.12.<your-domain-name.com>.
_minecraft._tcp.1.13          IN SRV    1 100 25566 1.13.<your-domain-name.com>.
```

(I did not need a srv record for 1.14 since my 1.14 minecraft server was already on the 25565 port which is the default port of minecraft.)

And the A records:

```
1.12                          IN A      <your server IP>
1.13                          IN A      <your server IP>
1.14                          IN A      <your server IP>
```

Comment: Your answer is clear, short, and correct. It's not clear why the accepted answer was accepted. This worked for me. As a comment states on the accepted answer, the example seems to be more like a load balancing setup. I'm not sure why it's getting up-votes, except if they voted before trying and then glossed over the details because they figured it out despite the mistake.

Comment: This is the correct answer, in my opinion. I don't know why the "accepted answer" got so many upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Use nginx on the server as a proxy that will listen to port A and multiplex to port B or C.
2. If you use AWS you can use the load balancer to redirect the request to specific port based on the [host](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-host-based-routing-and-increased-rules-on-its-application-load-balancer/).

Answer (score 0):

Use SRV record.
If you are using freenom go to cloudflare.com and connect your freenom server to cloudflare (freenom doesn't support srv records) use _minecraft as service tcp as protocol and your ip as target, priority - 0, weight - 0 and port - the port you want to use.(i know this because i was in the same situation) Do the same for any domain provider. (sorry if i made spell mistakes)

Edit: Just realized that most of the things I typed didn't make any sense.