# DNS to external IP address with different port

Tags: dns

This might be a tricky question but I'd like to forward a domain to a website that's currently hosted on an IP address on a different port.
This website is not operated so I have no control over the port number.

Specifically http://chaincoinexplorer.com
Should load up this: http://104.238.153.140:3001/

Currently it just redirects. But that's not good enough, and neither is stealth forwarding or iframes or anything of that sort.
If it's impossible through dns or similar, I can just clone the website. But I'd like to make sure there is absolutely no better way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect DNS to different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use DNS to map the request to another port: browser only use DNS to map the hostname to an IP address. So, you MUST use a redirect, as you have done.